# Rshiny - maptiles show when app runs from Rstudio desktop but not server

Tags: r, rstudio

just dipping my toe into Rstudio server for the first time. I have some custom map tiles which were showing when I ran the app in RStudio Desktop but in Rstudio Server I see a greyed-out area. Don't know why this should be?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
mymap <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles("http:/level123.co.uk/ds16/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", option = tileOptions(tms = TRUE), leafletOptions(minZoom = 0, maxZoom = 17)) %>% 
  setView(-0.3224, 51.2322,  10) %>% 
  addMarkers(-0.3224, 51.2322)
mymap
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: Sorry I hope the edited code is better. Above works in Desktop. In RStudio Server I see the marker but it seems the tiles aren't being fetched.